# How to connect multiple TLM ports to UVM Sequencer?

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, verification, uvm

There is requirement to send transactions (tr) from a `uvm_component` to a BFM, a `uvm_driver`. But, there are multiple "imp" ports from component. I am planning to write a task to get transactions from those ports and run them on sequencer like below.

[image]

The current idea is to write something similar to the pseudo-code below in the task,

```
fork
 forever begin
  tr tran;
  tlm_c1.get(tran);
  // add transaction delay
  sequencer_handle.execute_item(tran);
 end 
 forever begin 
   tr tran;
   tlm_c2.get(tran);
   // add transaction delay
   sequencer_handle.execute_item(tran);
 end
join none
```

Will it work? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches that come to mind.

1. [UVM TLM FIFO](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1b/html/files/tlm1/uvm_tlm_fifos-svh.html)

This class provides storage of transactions between two independently running processes.

2. [UVM Virtual Sequencers](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsDVCon2016_Vsequencers.pdf)

Tests that require coordinated generation of stimulus using multiple driving agents need to use virtual sequences.